# Is there a better way to check the database for a unique value that works for both update and insert then below

Tags: sql-server, unique

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE MyTable.RecordId <> @RecordId AND MyTable.UniqueColumn = @UniqueValue)
        BEGIN
            SELECT 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT 0
        END
```

NOTE: I use the NOLOCK so it checks for pending inserts and update (i.e someone update / changing the UniqueColumn)

NOTE: I use the "IF EXISTS(" so it stops search after finding the first match

NOTE: I use the "MyTable.RecordId <> @RecordId" so that it does not find itself as a match.

NOTE: If inserting the recordId would be negative one or zero.

Comment: Please define "better":  Faster? Less code? Clearer code?

Comment: Is there a faster way for this code to execute without losing any functionality?

Comment: Try select 1 instead of select *

Comment: @dman2306: that doesn't make any difference, since the `IF EXISTS()` only checks for the **existance** of rows - it doesn't actually **return** any data (it return a 0 or 1, depending on whether rows exist or not).

Comment: If there's an index on `MyTable.UniqueColumn`, and the data type of `@UniqueValue` is the same as that of `MyTable.UniqueColumn`, your query will execute plenty fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's "better", but it's more to-the-point:

```
select
  case 
    when
      exists ( select * from ... where ... )
    then 1 
    else 0 
  end as IsThereOrNot
```

...and can be used with other expressions (if you need 'em).

Note: select * is appropriate for existence checks, and nolock isn't going to change anything - there's an implicit transaction for the scope of the select.

I think it's better (easier to use the results by your consumers) if you name your columns (IsThereOrNot in the example)